# How to align text to the left side of centered text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, text-alignment

So we want a solution to this alignment requirement:

```
---------------------------
|         BlaBla          |
|    Bla BlaBla BlaBla    |
|        BlaBla Bl        |
---------------------------
|    OtherText            |
---------------------------
```

The centered, **dynamic** *BlaBla* text lives with the *OtherText* in a responsive width container.
The *OtherText* should be aligned left, but (and that is the root problem) still in an alignment with the left side of the centered text.

So with simple CSS I can only achieve this:

```
---------------------------
|         BlaBla          |
|    Bla BlaBla BlaBla    |
|        BlaBla Bl        |
---------------------------
|OtherText                |
---------------------------
```

Who knows a super awesome CSS or JavaScript solution?

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
}
.slider .title {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
}
.slider .btn {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <h1 class="title">BlaBla<br>Bla BlaBla BlaBla<br>BlaBla Bl</h1>
  <span class="btn">OtherText</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post here your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: Have a look at the code you've posted. Works alright, huh?

Comment: @VisioN _"OtherText"_ needs to align the furthest left edge of _"Bla."_ In this example that would be the _"Bla"_ of the second row of text.

Comment: Not really. The character "O" of "OtherText" should be in one line with the outer, left "B" of "Bla BlaBla..." - exactly like @hungerstar posted

Comment: @ЮнгвиртТони Gotcha. Please check my solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution would be to add a container with `display: inline-block;`:

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
.slider .container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
.slider .btn {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="title">BlaBla<br>Bla BlaBla BlaBla<br>BlaBla Bl</h1>
    <div class="btn">OtherText</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow! AWESOME! I'm doing some tests before accepting it.

Comment: @ЮнгвиртТони Also make sure you use element with `display: block;` for `.btn` (as `<div>`) or just add `display: block;` for your `<span>` in the markup.

Comment: This answer's `h1` has three lines of centered text. If you change one of the lines to something long and then resize the window so that it doesn't all fit on one line, the solution no longer works. For example, I changed the top line from "BlaBla" to "This here top line has a whole lot of text, wouldn't you agree?" and recorded this demo: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6ubeq.gif

Answer (score 0):

```
.slider .btn {
    text-align: left;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

that should work

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
       <tr>
           <td class="title"> <h1>BlaBla<br>Bla BlaBla BlaBla<br>BlaBla Bl </h1>   </td>
      </tr>   
      <tr>
          <td class="btn">  hola  </td>
      </tr>
    </table>


    table .title {
      text-align: center;
    }

    table .btn {
      text-align: left;
    }

    table {
      margin:0 auto;  
    }

    table td {
      border: 1px solid red; 
      padding: 0px;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k5kagxju/

Comment: Can you do this without table?

Comment: @VisioN yes, you are correct. This is not a good use of `<table>`.

Comment: @VisioN using a table give a solution to the question. So i think it's good. He can still choose to don't use it.

Comment: @Alist3r you are correct that using `<table>` provides a solution to the OPs question. That doesn't automatically make it a good answer. Intended use of a `<table>` is not to align two paragraphs in a particular way. It depends on context. Here, the use of `<table>` is not in a context for using one.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires two extra elements in your markup which I'm not a big fan of but meets your requirements.

The *"Bla"* text needs to govern the width of *"OtherText"*. By placing both text blocks in an `inline-block` element, that containing element will only be as wide as the largest child, which in this instance is the *"Bla"* text. The second container is used to center the first containing element.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="alignment">
        <p>
            Bla Bla<br>
            Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla<br>
            Bla Bla Bla
        </p>
        <p>
            OtherText
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container,
.alignment {
    text-align: center;
}
.alignment {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container p:nth-of-type(2) {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: I think this is matching @Юнгвирт Тони expectation.